# How can I check that a Bash script argument is a user-defined function?

Tags: bash, unix

I need to validate that, when running a bash script via the command line, the user is calling, as their first argument, one of the user defined functions in the same script.  I know that there is a built in bash command "type," so I am trying to use that.  However, I can't seem to get it to work - even when I run the script in -x mode, what is returned from "type -t $1" is just an empty string.

I have tried `$(type -t $1)`, `$(type -t "$1")`, `if [ $(type -t "$1") = "foo"]`, etc.

Nothing is ever indicated when I test with a function that it is a function, and nothing is returned when I try to validate.  I am very new to Bash scripting, apologies if this question is asked elsewhere, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Is the function already defined at the point where this `type` command is being used? That is, have the function definitions been executed by that point in the script?

Comment: oh man, no! Ugh I can't believe I didn't consider that, sorry, not used to Bash/not compiled languages.  So it seems that if I wanted to validate arguments as soon as the script is run (prior to function definitions).... it's not possible?

Comment: @JillMario Believe it or not, this can happen in some compiled languages also, like ones that compile top-level definitions separately and instantiate the compiled versions of those definitions one by one from the file. You can structure your Bash script like a typical compiled language program. Put everything in functions; call one of them `main` or whatever and just at the very bottom, call `main`.  Your `main` can then be the top of the file, if you prefer that.

Comment: Python compiles to byte-code, yet doesn't handle forward-references from top-level expressions; i.e. you can't call `foo(3)` and **later** have a `def foo(arg):`.

Comment: @Kaz, that's interesting, thanks!  I will do that, and thanks for your quick reply

Comment: @Kaz to be honest, I thought Python was interpreted..... I have a lot to learn it seems